# Data transfer from Intranet to Extranet using CSOM or SharePoint Web Services or Rest Services?

Tags: web-services, extranet, intranet

I have an Intranet Site A and extranet sharepoint site B in two different farms. I want transfer data (list items and doc's) from Intranet SiteA to Extranet SiteB. Please let me what are the possible ways to acomplish this. I am thinking of is CSOM or sharepoint web services like lists.asmx or rest services like listdata.svc. I am not sure to use any of these as they are in different farms. I am supposed to work only through a particular port I guess, does managed client object model work in this case. sorry if I am asking any basic questions.

Please guide me. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All three options you list will work fine against multiple farms.

As much as possible I'd stick with CSOM or REST. And as you want to work with both Documents and List items the CSOM is probably the best choice.

Comment: CSOM is actually built on top of WCF so it is almost the same as Web Services options from port config perspective.

Comment: thanks for reply guys, Can you also please also help how to set up a particular port for the CSOM and what is the default port on which the CSOM runs.

Comment: `var context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010:3695");` or `var context = new MySiteDataContext(new Uri("http://sp2010:3695/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));` CSOM and REST are pure HTTP requests, so you just specify the portnumber as usually and the default is port 80.